# Efficiently summarizing and transforming a table of data using tidyverse functions

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a relatively large data file that looks like (a), and need create a structure like (b). Thus I need to calculate the sum of Amount times Coeficient for each ID and each year.

[image]

I quickly hacked something together using nested for loops, but thats of course terribly inefficient:

```
library(tidyverse)

data  <- tibble(
    id=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C"),
    year=c(2002,2002,2004,2002,2003,2003,2005),
    amount=c(1000,1500,1000,500,1000,1000,500),
    coef=rep(0.5,7)
)

years  <- sort(unique(data$year))
ids  <- unique(data$id)

result  <- matrix(0,length(ids),length(years)) %>%
    as.tibble() %>% setNames(., years)

for (i in seq_along(ids)){
    for (j in seq_along(years)){
        d  <- filter(data, id==ids[i] & year== years[j])
        if (nrow(d)!=0){
            result[i,j]  <- sum(d$amount*d$coef)
        }
    }
}
result  <- add_column(result, ID=ids, .before = 1)
```

I was wondering how one could solve this efficiently using `map()`, `group_by()` or any other tidyverse functions.

Thanks in advance for helpful suggestions.

Comment: look up "long to wide [r] [[tidyverse]".

Comment: `?spread` will get you there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that seems to work. I'm sure there are others.

```
library(tidyverse)

id <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C")
year <- c(2002,2002,2004,2002,2003,2003,2005)
amount <- c(1000,1500,1000,500,1000,1000,500)
coef <- rep(0.5,7)

data <- tibble(id, year, amount, coef)

table <- data %>% 
  group_by(., id, year)  %>%  
  mutate(prod = amount*coef)%>%
  summarize(., sumprod = sum(prod)) %>%
  spread(., year, sumprod) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Comment: Ha ha...oops. I posted mine before I realized you'd cracked it. Good illustration that you can usually get to the same place in different ways. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to the tidyverse so seeing a different way is helpful ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint, this really is just one line:

```
result  <- data %>% group_by(id, year) %>% summarise(S=sum(amount*coef)) %>% spread(year, S)
```